# Py-StackExchange raise a valueError

Tags: python, stackexchange-api

I try to use the StackExchange API and I found the Py-StackExchange library for Python. I installed it through easy_install in Windows.

Here is the code:

```
from stackexchange import Site, StackOverflow

so = Site(StackOverflow)
my_favourite_guy = so.user(2309097)
print my_favourite_guy.reputation.format()
print len(my_favourite_guy.answers), 'answers'
```

And here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tasos\Desktop\test - Copy.py", line 8, in <module>
    my_favourite_guy = so.user(2309097)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\stackexchange\__init__.py", line 626, in user
    u, = self.users((nid,), **kw)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\stackexchange\__init__.py", line 631, in users
    return self._get(User, ids, 'users', kw)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\stackexchange\__init__.py", line 621, in _get
    return self.build(root, typ, coll, kw)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\stackexchange\__init__.py", line 598, in build
    json = self._request(url, kw)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\stackexchange\__init__.py", line 570, in _request
    json, info = request_mgr.json_request(url, new_params)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\stackexchange\web.py", line 120, in json_request
    return (json.loads(req.data), req.info)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 383, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

I saw in [Wiki](https://github.com/lucjon/Py-StackExchange/wiki/FAQ) the following but I don't use any proxy and the code version is the latest through easy_install:

> This is probably the result of some proxy/router mangling with request
>   headers. It could be that your router/proxy adds headers requesting
>   gzip data, but doesn't decompress it, and that you are running a
>   slightly old version of the code which does not deal with gzip
>   compression. In this case, just update to the latest version of the
>   library.

Comment: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/api-v1-shutdown is returned.

Comment: @MartijnPieters this means that the library is useless at the moment since it uses the old api version?

Comment: The PyPI release is indeed useless; install from GitHub instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [version on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-stackexchange) is well out of date (released 2011) and still uses API version 1.1, which has been [shut down](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/api-v1-shutdown).

The [Github codebase](https://github.com/lucjon/Py-StackExchange) has been updated to use API v2.2, install that directly:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/lucjon/Py-StackExchange
```

or using `easy_install`, download the current master zip:

```
easy_install https://github.com/lucjon/Py-StackExchange/archive/640eac1525baaf57474ddbc3be2b580f00e4f1e8.zip
```

To get answers listed you need to call `.fetch()`:

```
print len(my_favourite_guy.answers.fetch()), 'answers'
```

This only fetches the *first page* of answers:

```
>>> from stackexchange import Site, StackOverflow
>>> so = Site(StackOverflow)
>>> my_favourite_guy = so.user(2309097)
>>> print my_favourite_guy.reputation.format()
563
>>> print len(my_favourite_guy.answers.fetch()), 'answers'
19 answers
>>> my_favourite_guy = so.user(100297)
>>> print my_favourite_guy.reputation.format()
251.2k
>>> print len(my_favourite_guy.answers.fetch()), 'answers'
30 answers
```

I have a few more than 30 answers, last time I checked. Use `.extend_next()` calls to fetch the next query set, until you run out.